# Doubly Linked List with generic node type

Tags: java, generics

I need a doubly linked list that can work on different node implementations.  Note that I do not want nodes that contain generic data, like `DoublyLinkedNode<T>`, but something like `DoublyLinkedList<N extends DoublyLinkedNode<T>>`.

To be precise, I use the list in the general case with standard nodes, but in other parts of my program I need nodes with additional fields. So I implemented the general node as

```
public class DoublyLinkedNode<T> {
    DoublyLinkedNode<T> before, after;
    T value;
}
```

and the special type as

```
public class DoublyLinkedSpecialNode<T, S> extends DoublyLinkedNode<T> {
    S specialValue;
}
```

Now in my DoublyLinkedList implementation I want to be able to handle both cases at one, because all the code basically fiddles around with the pointers that are obviously common to both implementations.

This gives a few requirements:

1) When I use the special node, I want to be able to return it as the `DoublyLinkedSpecialNode` type to be able to access the additional fields.

2) The list must use a DoublyLinkedNode type to access the pointers of the nodes.

3) The list is assigning the pointed-to nodes to other nodes, e.g. `head = node.after;`, so the type of the pointers in the special node must be the same as the type in the list.

Extending the list makes no sense because then I could not change the return type of the methods. Therefore I tried two ideas without success:

**The already mentioned solution: Generic node type that extends from DLN**

The list would look like this:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T, N extends DoublyLinkedNode<T>> {
    N head, tail;
    N tail() {
        return tail; // OK
    }
    void remove(N node) {
        if (head == node) {
            head = node.after; // Type error
        }
...
```

This solution conflicts with requirement 3), because in the list the type is an N that extends from DLN, but in the node implementation N the pointer is of the type of the base class/interface DLN (the pointer type could theoretically be more general than N).

**Base DLN instead of generics**

In this case the list works on the base class node and accepts the subclasses because of polymorphism:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> {
    DoublyLinkedNode<T> head, tail;
    DoublyLinkedNode<T> tail() {
        return tail; 
    }
    void remove(DoublyLinkedNode<T> node) {
        if (head == node) {
            head = node.after; // OK
        }
...
```

But tail() can only return nodes as the general type, conflicting with 1). I would prefer not to use casting, because I assume it's bad practice (?) but also because the implementation is performance critical. There surely is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that is okay-ish, not very performant but more elegant than the last solution.

The idea ist to use only one type of nodes, and wrap the varying content in a generic container. The DLN code looks like this:

```
public class DoublyLinkedNode<C> {
    DoublyLinkedNode<C> before, after;
    C content;

    public static class ValueContent<T> {
        T value;
    }

    public static class ValueSpecialContent<T, S> extends ValueContent<T> {
        S specialValue;
    }
}
```

The list implementation then looks something like this:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<C> {
    DoublyLinkedNode<C> head, tail;

    public DoublyLinkedNode<C> head() {
        return head;
    }

    void remove(DoublyLinkedNode<C> node) {
        if (head == node) {
            head = node.after;
...
```

And I can access the special field from the calling class like this:

```
DoublyLinkedList<SpecialContent<SpecialType>> list;
SpecialType s = list.head().content.specialValue;
```

There is some overhead because each node has to instantiate that container class, but I think it's still better than casting. I have to check the performance impact.